# How do I delete multiple rows at once in DOORS?

Tags: ibm-doors

## Background

I am trimming outdated rows of information from a DOORS file. The way I know how to delete rows is to do them one at a time by the following procedure:

1. Select the row I want to delete
2. Open the **Table** menu
3. Wave over the **Delete** option
4. Click on the **Row** option
5. Repeat for each row.

## Question

Is there a way to do a bulk delete of multiple rows at once in DOORS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So- this is a bit trickier than it appears, mostly because DOORS does not allow for non-sequential selection of items without DXL scripting.

If I were doing this, I would do the following:

First, set the first element of each row that is going to be deleted to something recognizable- for example, "||DELETED||"

Next, I would run the following code:

```
// Use the current module
Module m = current
// Grab the first object
Object o = first ( m )
// Loop through the objects in the module - using a deletion in the loop, so no for o in m
while ( !null o ) {
    // Check for our deletion flag
    if ( o."Object Text" "" == "||DELETED||" ) {
        // Grab the parent object - this will actually be the 'row object'
        Object oP = parent ( o )
        // Set 'o' to point to the object right before the deletion (to allow loop to continue)
        o = previous ( parent ( o ) )
        // Softdelete that row object
        softDelete ( oP )
    }
    // Go to the next object (on the last object, will set equal to null)
    o = next ( o )
}
```

This may not be the best way to go about this- I've always wanted to take a crack at non-sequential selection in the GUI. But it should accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: I have no way to test this, since at my place of work, I do not have permissions to create comprehensive DXL scripts like this.